# Line Breaks in form object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Please let me know if this is a duplicate post, but I was not able to find a solution to my issue. Its gotta be something simple...

I'm trying to use javascript to build a form. The html for the form is as follows:

```
<form>
  Time: <input type="time"> <br>
  Performer: <input type="text"><br>
  Link: <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

what I'm trying to do is build this exact form using javascript, but the elements are all showing up on the same line. Here's my javascript function:

```
function addPerformance(){
var brk = document.createElement("br");
var form = document.createElement("form");

//create time element
var time = document.createElement("input");
time.setAttribute("type", "time");
form.appendChild(time);
form.appendChild(brk);

//create perfomer element
var perf = document.createElement("input");
perf.setAttribute("type", "text");
form.appendChild(perf);
form.appendChild(brk);

//create link element
var link = document.createElement("input");
link.setAttribute("type", "text");
form.appendChild(link);
form.appendChild(brk);

//create submit element
var sub = document.createElement("input");
sub.setAttribute("type", "submit");
sub.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
form.appendChild(sub);
form.appendChild(brk);

document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

"form.appendChild(brk)" is what I thought would add those line breaks like in the html example but its not working. Ultimately, I just want each element of the form to be in a single column. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `form.appendChild(brk);` the second time, it moves the *HTMLElement* referenced by `brk` from where it is to the new position; i.e. removes it from the first place.

Append clones instead

```
 form.appendChild(brk.cloneNode());
```

Comment: Also, what I did was declare the brk variable outside of my function call so that I can use the brk.cloneNode() in all of my functions without having to create a new element every time.